# Регулярное выражение в htaccess

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .htaccess, perl, opencart

Есть необходимость сделать редирект с адреса типа `site.com/product/title` на адрес типа `site.com/title`.

При использовании кода данного вида:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/product/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

получаю редирект на ту же страницу, на которую и обратился, и в итоге зацикливание редиректов.

Что мне нужно изменить? Что не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы написал:

```
RewriteRule ^/product/(.*) http://site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: При таком вариант переадресация не происходит в принципе, и я ухожу на 404-ую.

Comment: Исправил на следующий вариант, и получил желаемый результат.

RewriteRule product\/(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]

Не знаю в чем смысл, но заработало. Спасибо.